# Sets are unordered but it still supports subtraction of 2 sets, how does it work internally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

```
>>> my_set = {False, 3, 4.5, 6, 'cat'}
>>> your_Set = {99, 3, 100}
>>> my_set
{False, 3, 4.5, 6, 'cat'}
>>> your_Set
{3, 99, 100}
```

We can see that both sets are unordered, but now if I do subtraction :

```
>>> my_set - your_Set
{False, 4.5, 6, 'cat'}
```

It gave me the correct result. How it is implemented internally?

Comment: What does set difference have to do with ordering?

Comment: I understand that it's a difference my_set.difference(your_Set) will also give me the same result, but I am trying to understand how python interpret subtraction on sets. It might be a dumb question, but will help in understand python implementation better

Comment: Python interprets `-` on sets as set difference. What does any of this have to do with ordering?

Comment: It could be like this `result = copy_of(my_set); for e in your_set { result.remove(e); }`  That is pseudo-code.  Notice that it does not depend on ordering.

Comment: Or `result = empty_set(); for e in your_set { if e not in your_set { result.add(e); } }`

Answer (score 2):

Sets subtraction (or any other set operation) has nothing to with order within the sets.

`A - B` (or `A.difference(B)`) where both are sets means a set with elements that are in A and not in B.

See more about [sets operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations).

Comment: I understand that it's a difference my_set.difference(your_Set) will also give me the same result, but I am trying to understand how python interpret subtraction on sets. It might be a dumb question, but will help in understand python implementation better

Comment: @Preeti I'm not sure what you mean by "how python interpret subtraction on sets". It 'simply' builds a new set with elements in A and not in B.

Comment: in case of numpy it does element wise subtraction if we subtract 2 numpy arrays, in the same way I was trying to understand sets

Comment: @Preeti what does `numpy` have to do with anything? `numpy` provides multidimensional arrays, not `set` objects. These are totally unrelated things. Conceptually, `set` objects work like mathematical sets. This is what the difference means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement

Comment: Sir, numpy is just a example which I put forward in order to understand that I am thinking this subtraction as element wise subtraction not in terms of 'in' operator, that's how ordering of sets comes in my mind. Not comparing numpy and sets just the element wise subtraction I wanted to bring in picture

Comment: @Preeti: Are you saying you thought `{False, 4.5, 6, 'cat'}` was the result of elementwise subtraction?

Comment: No, sir I understood that it can't happen with elementwise, but I wanted to understand that elementwise will be easy to implement rather than a "in" operation, so why can't that happen

Comment: @Preeti you are not making any sense. It has been explained to you many times what the difference operator means for sets. What, *exactly* do you not understand?

Comment: While it may be discouraging to be told that one is not making sense, it may be constructive.  Sometimes, one needs a "mental kick" to cause one to reconsider some incorrect thinking.  *"Sometimes it's hard to explain because of difference in thoughts or understanding."* - True.  However, if you don't succeed in explaining what you are thinking, we won't be able to understand what you think ... and we won't be able to explain what the mistake in your thinking is.  (And there definitely is a mistake.  You can see the evidence that Set difference *does* work, and that sets are not ordered.)

Comment: Thank you @StephenC  for making me understand, really appreciate it. I will try to make it clear. I understand how it will be working using "in" operator that's why it gave me the correct result in my example. I just wanted to know that why python people who wrote the actual implementation for sets didn't prefer to use elementwise subtraction because of ordering or any other reason

Comment: Without looking at the python implementation code, we can't tell how they chose to implement it.  So we can't tell whether they chose to use element-wise subtraction or not.  However, you can see from the two possible approaches that I gave you that you can implement set subtraction without ordering, whether you use element-wise subtraction or element-wise addition.  See comments on question.

Comment: Thank you @StephenC understood.

Comment: If you want to look at the actual implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c - at about line 1539.  I hope you know how to read C.  It turns out that different approaches are used, depending on the actual types of the "set-like" objects.